# Search and sort by relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have project in Laravel 5.8.

I have this function:

```
public function getCourserFromDates(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo)
{
    return $this->model->getCourserFromDates( $dateFrom,  $dateTo)->get();
}
```

And my models:

```
class Course extends Model implements Sitemapable
{
    use HasSitemap,
        Seoable,
        SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'course_category_id',
        'basic_course_id',
        'default_currency_id',
        'short_name',
        'color',
        'price',
        'has_negotiable_price',
        'deposit',
        'certificate_title',
        'certificate_description',
        'certificate_number',
        'is_active',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
        'deleted_by'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'course_category_id' => 'integer',
        'basic_course_id' => 'integer',
        'default_currency_id' => 'integer',
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
        'price' => 'float',
        'deposit' => 'float',
        'created_by' => 'integer',
        'updated_by' => 'integer',
        'deleted_by' => 'integer'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'name'
    ];

    protected $with = [
        'courseDescriptions'
    ];

    public function courseCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseCategory::class);
    }

    public function basicCourse()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class);
    }

    public function defaultCurrency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
    }

    public function courseTerms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CourseTerm::class);
    }

    public function closestCourseTerms()
    {
        return $this
            ->courseTerms()
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->whereDate('starting_at', '>', today()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->whereDate('starting_at', '<=', today()->addDays(config('courses.closest_terms_within_days', 0)))
            ->orderBy('starting_at');
    }

    public function getCourserFromDates(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo)
    {
        return $this
            ->with('courseTerms')
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->whereHas('courseTerms', function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo){
                $query->whereBetween('starting_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]);
                $query->orderBy('starting_at');
            });
    }

    public function closestConfirmedCourseTerms()
    {
        return $this->closestCourseTerms
            ->where('is_confirmed', true)->all();
    }

    public function closestNotConfirmedCourseTerms()
    {
        return $this->closestCourseTerms
            ->where('is_confirmed', false)->all();
    }

    public function closestCourseTerm()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasOne(CourseTerm::class)
            ->withCount('courseParticipants')
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->whereDate('starting_at', '>', today()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('starting_at');
    }

    public function courseParticipants()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\CourseParticipant','App\Models\CourseTerm');
    }

    public function courseDescriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CourseDescription');
    }

    public static function allForSitemap(): Collection
    {
        return self::where('is_active', true)
            ->select(['id','is_active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])
            ->get();
    }

    public function hasTranslation($locale = null)
    {
        $courseDescriptions = $this->courseDescriptions ?? $this->courseDescriptions();

        return $courseDescriptions
            ->where('locale', $locale ?: \App::getLocale() )
            ->count() === 1;
    }

    public function translatedDescriptions($locale = null)
    {
        $courseDescriptions = $this->courseDescriptions ?? $this->courseDescriptions();

        if( $this->hasTranslation($locale) )
        {
            return $courseDescriptions->where('locale', $locale ?: \App::getLocale() )->first();
        }
        /*
         * Playin' dirty
         */
        if( $this->hasTranslation('pl') )
        {
            return $courseDescriptions->where('locale', 'pl' )->first();
        }

        throw new \Exception('Requested language not found');
    }

    public function getNameAttribute() {
        $description = $this->courseDescriptions->where('locale', \App::getLocale())->first();

        return $description instanceof CourseDescription
            ? $description->name
            : $this->short_name;
    }

    public function getShortDescriptionAttribute() {
        return data_get($this->courseDescriptions->where('locale', \App::getLocale())->first(), 'short_description', "");
    }

    public function getDescriptionAttribute() {
        return data_get($this->courseDescriptions->where('locale', \App::getLocale())->first(), 'description', "");
    }

    public function getSlugAttribute() {
        return data_get($this->courseDescriptions->where('locale', \App::getLocale())->first(), 'slug', "");
    }

    public function getIsRenewalAttribute() : bool {
        return $this->basicCourse instanceof self;
    }

    public function courseTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CourseTag::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->using(CourseTag::class);
    }

    public function getUrlAttribute() {
        return ! empty($slug = $this->slug)
            ? route('front.course.show', ['slug' => $slug])
            : route('front.course.find', ['id' => $this->id]);
    }

    /**
     * @param Builder $query
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeWhereActiveWithTerms(Builder $query) : Builder
    {
        return $query
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('course_terms')
                    ->whereRaw("course_id = courses.id and is_active = 1 and starting_at > '" . today()->format('Y-m-d') . "'");
        });
    }

    public function getCourseCategoryUrlAttribute() {
        if(empty($this->courseCategory)) {
            return null;
        }

        if(is_null($this->courseCategory->parent_category_id)) {
            return $this->courseCategory->url;
        }

        return $this->courseCategory->parentCategory->url;
    }

    public function getLocalizedUrlsAttribute() {
        $urls = [];

        foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $locale => $properties) {
            if(! is_null($slug = $this->getSlug($locale))) {
                $urls[$locale] = array_merge($properties, [
                    'url' => LaravelLocalization::getURLFromRouteNameTranslated($locale,  'routes.front.course.show', ['slug' => $slug])
                ]);
            }
        }

        return $urls;
    }

    public function getSlug($locale): string {
        return data_get($this->courseDescriptions->where('locale', $locale)->first(), 'slug', "");
    }

    public function getGtagViewItemDataAttribute(): array
    {
        $viewItemData = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'category' => data_get($this->courseCategory, 'name', '')
        ];

        if(! $this->has_negotiable_price)
        {
            $viewItemData['price'] = $this->price;
        }

        return $viewItemData;
    }
}



class CourseTerm extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'starting_at',
        'days',
        'course_id',
        'max_participants',
        'additional_notes',
        'is_active',
        'is_confirmed',
        'diary_generated_at'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'diary_generated_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'course_id' => 'integer',
        'days' => 'integer',
        'max_participants' => 'integer',
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
        'is_confirmed' => 'boolean',
        'starting_at' => 'date:Y-m-d'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'date'
    ];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Course');
    }

    public function courseParticipants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CourseParticipant');
    }

    public function freeReservations() : int
    {
        return (int) array_key_exists('course_participants_count', $this->attributes)
            ? $this->max_participants - $this->course_participants_count
            : $this->max_participants - $this->courseParticipants()->count();
    }

    public function getHasFreeReservationsAttribute() : bool {
        return $this->freeReservations() > 0;
    }

    public function getReservationsProgressInPercentAttribute() : int {
        if($this->max_participants == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return (int) round(($this->max_participants - $this->freeReservations())/ $this->max_participants * 100);
    }

    public function getUnifiedDaysAttribute() : int {
        return max($this->days - 1, 0);
    }

    public function getEndingAtAttribute() : Carbon {
        return Carbon::parse($this->starting_at)->addDays($this->unified_days);
    }

    public function getDateAttribute($value) : string
    {
        if($this->unified_days == 0) {
            return $this->starting_at->format("d-m-Y");
        }

        $endingAt = $this->ending_at;

        if($this->starting_at->isSameMonth($endingAt)) {
            return $this->starting_at->format('d') . '-' . $endingAt->format('d.m.Y');
        } else if($this->starting_at->isSameYear($endingAt)) {
            return $this->starting_at->format('d.m') . '-' . $endingAt->format('d.m.Y');
        } else {
            return $this->starting_at->format('d.m.Y') . '-' . $endingAt->format('d.m.Y');
        }
    }

    public function getStartingAtForHumansAttribute() : string {
        return Date::parse($this->starting_at)->format('j F Y');
    }

    public function getEndingAtForHumansAttribute() : string {
        return Date::parse($this->starting_at)
            ->addDays($this->unified_days)
            ->format('j F Y');
    }

    public function getDaysToAttribute() : int {
        return Carbon::parse($this->starting_at)->diffInDays(today());
    }

    public function getSignUrlAttribute() : string {
        if(! $this->has_free_reservations) {
            return "#";
        }

        return route('front.order.sign', ['courseTermId' => $this->id]);
    }

    public function hasActiveCourse() : bool {
        return $this->course instanceof Course && $this->course->is_active;
    }

    public function canSignByDate(): bool {
        return $this->starting_at > today()->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

I have problem with this part of my code:

```
public function getCourserFromDates(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo) { return $this ->with('courseTerms') ->where('is_active', true) ->whereHas('courseTerms', function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo){ $query->whereBetween('starting_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]); $query->orderBy('starting_at'); }); }
```

Here's what I need:

Courses with dates within the given range
Sort the results (course_terms) by startet_at ASC
Currently, I have records in the database for 2020-12-22 - 2020-12-27. When my data_from is 2020-12-25, I can still see the cource_terms for 2020-12-22.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: code seems good, can you provide records from DB and certain params dateFrom and dateTo?

Comment: its return this sql: select * from `courses` where `is_active` = 1 and exists (select * from `course_terms` where `courses`.`id` = `course_terms`.`course_id` and `starting_at` between '2020-12-25' and '2020-12-31' and `course_terms`.`deleted_at` is null order by `starting_at` asc) and `courses`.`deleted_at` is null

Comment: a little prune would be appreciate. you can share only need to review code with eliminating not necessary codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are eager loading the relationship `courseTerms` with the call to `with('courseTerms')`. This does not do any constraining/filtering. This will always load that full relationship as needed. If you want to restrict what is eager loaded you need to "constrain the eager loading" by using an anonymous function to filter it down. In this case you would probably use the same filtering you did with the `whereHas` call:

```
$dates = [$dataFrom, $dateTo];

$filter = function ($query) use ($dates) {
    $query->whereBetween('starting_at', $dates)
        ->orderBy('starting_at');
};

return $this->where('is_active', true)
    ->with(['courseTerms' => $filter])
    ->whereHas('courseTerms', $filter);
```